# Adding a second Heroku app to my local repo, I'm denied access to my apps

Tags: ruby, git, heroku, cloud, heroku-toolbelt

I originally had a setup like:

```
git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.org: (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org: (push)
stage   git@heroku.com: (fetch)
stage   git@heroku.com: (push)
```

where I could push and pull from stage without an issue and run commands like

```
heroku run console --app stage
```

however, I added a production app locally leaving me with:

```
origin  git@bitbucket.org: (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org: (push)
prod    git@heroku.com: (fetch)
prod    git@heroku.com: (push)
stage   git@heroku.com: (fetch)
stage   git@heroku.com: (push)
```

and now when I run

```
heroku logs --app prod
```

I get:

```
 !    You do not have access to the app prod.
```

as well as for stage.

I even tried doing heroku logout, and heroku login again, and explicitly logged in with the exact same email as the one listed as application owner for both apps, and it still is an issue.

What's going on?

Comment: Are you attempting to deploy to a production app and a staging app from the same repository? If so you need to be referencing the name of the application not the remote name. (i.e. `heroku logs --app the-name-of-the-production-app`).

Comment: If you'd rather use the remote name, use the following syntax: `heroku COMMAND --remote remote-name`

Comment: I discovered this was the case @TaylorGlaeser. Please submit an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've submitted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. If you want to use the `--app` flag you need to reference the actual name of the production heroku app.

Another option is to use the `--remote` flag so that you can execute commands based on the git remote without knowing the name of the app.

So for example you can run the following command on your production instance: `heroku logs --remote prod`

For clarification, to use the `--app` syntax, you would have to know the name of the production app: `heroku logs --app name-of-production-app`

Comment: For clarification, in this instance the actual app name was not the remote name of prod, but something else, so --app <realnamehere>